# How to find the maximal interval of existence for the following IVP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The IVP is:   $\frac{du}{dt} = u^2 (u-1)$ ; $u(0)=2$ .

Effort: I solved by using separation of variables method. And I got:  $$\ \ln(|u-1|) - \ln(|u|) + \frac{1}{u} = t + 1/2 -\ln(2)$$

But I am not able to obtain $u$ as an explicit function of $t$. The graph given by the above implicit equation supports the same.

So how do I find the maximal interval of existence? Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your right hand side is a continuous function with continuous partial (w.r.t. $u$) on the whole plane. Your (unique) solution must exit any rectangle in the plane. Next observe that, as $u\to\infty$, $t\to\ln 2-1/2$ and, as $u\to 1$, $t\to -\infty$. Therefore your solution has domain $(-\infty, \ln 2-1/2)$.